# share content of html meta tags in android webview/ android

Tags: java, android, html, android-activity

I try develope this function to share title,description,images and url form a remote url in webview android.

```
private void shareURL() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, webView.getUrl());
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, webView.getTitle());
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share This!"), 1000);
    }
```

**first issue:** it just print title for example in whatsapp.

I try change it to this:

```
String extraText = webView.getTitle() + "\n\n" + webView.getUrl();
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, extraText);
```

it works. But is it a right solution?

**second:**

I try add describtion and images:

in my html website I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta describtion="">
```

and this type of meta to images:

```
<meta property=og:image content="img-0.jpg"/>
<meta name=twitter:image content="img-0.jpg"/>
<link itemprop=image href="img-0.jpg"/>
```

Is it possible?